# How substr works on dates

Tags: oracle, substr

I am trying to understand a query in my application where it uses substr function.
I have gone through the documentation for [substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm), which looks simple and clear.

Now below is my query without using substr:

```
select last_day(to_date(to_char(add_months(TO_DATE('2004/10/25', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),1),'YYYY')||'0201','YYYYMMDD')) from dual;
```

This gives me result as `2/29/2004`. The above query just returns last day of Feb in simple words.

Now I am using `substr` as below:

```
select substr(last_day(to_date(to_char(add_months(TO_DATE('2004/10/25', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),1),'YYYY')||'0201','YYYYMMDD')),5,1) from dual;
```

So here the start value is 5 & length is 1, so I am expecting output as `2` looking at `2/29/2004`. but the actual output is `E`, I am not clear from where this `E` is coming as result.

Comment: check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c384/13, the date format  is not as you expected, thats because you substring on a date and not on a string

Comment: try to change nls_date_format at session level and then check your query. but its not advisable in production

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that? Multiple conversions from varchar to date to varchar to date seem rather strange. I wouldn't be surprised if there is a lot easier and more stable way to do that, that does not require converting a value back and forth between different representations

Comment: Passing a date to a string function like `substr` is almost always a bug waiting to happen, because Oracle will perform an implicit conversion (which will be dependent on the session's NLS settings at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `SUBSTR()` on `DATE` values. `SUBSTR()` works only on strings!

When you run `SUBSTR({DATE_VALUE}, ...)` then Oracle actually does following:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(
        TO_CHAR(
            {DATE_VALUE}, (SELECT VALUE FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT') 
        ), ...
    )
FROM dual;
```

What is the purpose of this query? Do you like to find out whether input year is a leap-year?

Comment: This query is already used in my application, I am trying to understand how it is printing `E` as output, can you please help me in understanding it

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead -

```
select substr(to_char(last_day(to_date(to_char(add_months(TO_DATE('2004/10/25', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),1),'YYYY')||'0201','YYYYMMDD')),'dd/mm/yyyy'),5,1)
from dual;
```

Comment: This query is already used in my application, I am trying to understand how it is printing `E` as output, can you please help me in understanding it

Comment: @user3181365, See the hotfix answer above which explains everything. It is due to format of the date.